# Tkinter - Variable tracing un class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, trace

I have a very simple question. Why this simple script doesn't work ?

```
import tkinter as tk

class App() :

    def __init__(self) :
    
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("200x200")
        self.entry_box()
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def entry_box(self) :
    
        def tracing(*arg) : print('ok !')
    
        var = tk.DoubleVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=var)
        entry.grid()
    
        var.trace_add("write", tracing)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

I mean, when I write in the Entry, there is no 'ok !' printed in the terminal.
This script works :

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

def tracing(*arg) : print('ok !')

var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=var)
entry.grid()

var.trace_add('write', tracing)
     
window.mainloop()
```

What is my error in the class ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Make sure that the variable doesn't go out of scope. Add `self.var = var` at the end of that method.

Comment: Great ! It works ! Thanks ! With the line self.var=var I make global the local variable var. Is it correct ?

Comment: No to make it global you will need to add `global var` at the start of that method. The `self.var = var` (which is better than using a global variable) assigns the variable `var` to `self` as an attribute. That way as long as that instance of the class is alive, the variable will not be deleted.

Comment: Ah okok, thanks for your answers